# What is actually happening when we terminate a process in Unix?

Tags: unix, process, operating-system

I understand a process is completed once it's been terminated, but how does Unix actually go about doing this? What's going on under the hood when we terminate a process? Are we simply removing the process from memory, or is there more to it it than that? Are there rules or exceptions to when the steps the operating system takes to terminate a process differs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question suffers from being extremely broad. Process termination is a complicated process that involves many divergent pages. At a high level . . . .

There is a lot more to it than just removing the process. The big challenge is to free all the resources that the process has allocated.

The big one is memory. All the user-space physical memory has to be deallocated. That involves reference counting because it is possible for multiple processes to share the same pages in physical memory. The all the page file (aka swap partition in Unix) space allocated to the process has to be freed.

The most complex problem is what to do with I/O. The cleanup has to handle any pending I/O operations. All I/O ports have to be closed (files, pipes, sockets).

I am just scratching the surface her for you to give an idea of what goes on.